# ROSARIA+Arduino

Tags: arduino, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI, I want to make my robot move using *Arduino* (with hand made motor controller) and *ROS Groovy*. The problem is I have no idea to connect ROSARIA to Arduino for this. I have installed ROSARIA and I can toggle I/Os in arduino using ROSArduinoBridge. I planned to use kinect and build a map using it. Can anyone tell me how I should *write a code for Arduino* to support for ROSARIA? What is **cmd_vel**?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107716/rosaria+arduino/) by [Hasitha](https://answers.ros.org/users/8076/hasitha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2013-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, is your robot a Pioneer, ActivMedia, MobileRobots or Adept?

If not, do not use rosaria which is dedicated to these robots.

You can use a ros_arduino_bridge or rosserial.

Rosserial is given with sample sketches to start easily:

http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials

---

Originally posted by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) with karma: 357 on 2013-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0